# Combine 3 OUTER APPLY into 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a select Query where I'm using 3 OUTER APPLY statements one the same table and the 1st condition is same for all and the rest is different. and I'm using it to get the SUM of the same field. Is there any way that I can Combine all these 3 into 1?

Below is how I have Done so far :

```
OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                PaymentAmount = SUM(PaymentAmount)
                FROM PMT
                    WHERE InvoiceId = INV.InvoiceId
                    GROUP BY InvoiceId
        )P2
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                PaymentAmount = SUM(PaymentAmount)
                FROM PMT
                    WHERE InvoiceId = INV.InvoiceId
                        AND PaymentBatchID <= PB.PaymentBatchID
                        GROUP BY InvoiceId
        )P3
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                PaymentAmount = SUM(PaymentAmount)
                FROM PMT
                    WHERE InvoiceId = INV.InvoiceId
                        AND PaymentBatchID <= PB.PaymentBatchID
                        AND PaymentID <= Pay.PaymentID
                        GROUP BY InvoiceId
        )P4
```

Table PMT Has the following Columns

```
InvoiceId - INT
PaymentId - INT
PaymentBatchId - INT
PaymentAmount - DECIMAL(10,2)
```

I tried Using Case inside the same OUTER APPLY, but Got The follwing Error

> Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 134
>
> Multiple columns are specified
> in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference.
>
> If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that
> outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Comment: Does your main query also have GROUP BY InvoiceId?

Comment: No, Main Query contains simple Joins from multipel tables @sepupic

Answer (score 0):

use CASE ... WHEN for the conditions

```
OUTER APPLY
(
        SELECT
               P2_PaymentAmount = SUM(x.PaymentAmount),
               P3_PaymentAmount = SUM(CASE WHEN x.PaymentBatchID <= PB.PaymentBatchID THEN x.PaymentAmount END),
               P4_PaymentAmount = SUM(CASE WHEN x.PaymentBatchID <= PB.PaymentBatchID
                                            AND x.PaymentID <= Pay.PaymentID THEN x.PaymentAmount END)
        FROM   
               PMT x
        WHERE  
               x.InvoiceId = INV.InvoiceId

) P234
```

Comment: I Tried this first But got an Error. I've updated it on the Question.

Comment: Oh.. just the alias, i have changed the alias to `P234`, update your query and try

Comment: I still have the error Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Comment: please post the actual query

Comment: actual Query is too long to paste here. But I'm using these columns directly in the Select

Comment: can't really help you much without knowing the schema and the query, sample data and expected result